# Прошу помочь составить Regexp c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть Regexp, который находит строку в скобках "верхнего уровня":

`(\()((?>[^()]+|\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!)))(\))`

Пример:

`3.786 + 2x * ((1 + 1 - (2 + 4)) + 12*31) = pow(3, -2(5-4)) + 3/4`

[image: ![![введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу что бы искались только те строки, в которых нет знака `,`. Можно как то его исключить из результата?

То есть, я хочу что бы в данном примере нашёлся только 1 матч, тот что выделен зелёным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124569/discussion-on-question-by-kuzcode----regexp-c).

Answer (score 4):

Не ответ конечно, но раз уж код написал, не пропадать же добру. Делает примерно то же,что регулярка

```
IEnumerable<string> GetMatches(string input)
{   
    int ind = 0;
    
    while(ind < input.Length)
    {
        while(ind < input.Length && input[ind] != '(') ind++;
        var start = ind;
        var deep = 1; 
        ind++;
        
        while(ind < input.Length && deep > 0)
        {
            if (input[ind] == '(') deep++;
            if (input[ind] == ')') deep--;
            ind++;
        }

        if (deep == 0)
        {
            var ret = input.Substring(start, ind - start);
            if (!ret.Contains(',')) yield return ret;
        }           
    }   
}
```

проверка

```
var exp = "3.786 + 2x * ((1 + 1 - (2 + 4)) + 12*31)) = pow(3, -2(5-4)) + 3/4";
foreach (var m in GetMatches(exp))
    Console.WriteLine(m);
```

Вывод

```
((1 + 1 - (2 + 4)) + 12*31)
```

Comment: Даже если использовать регулярное выражение, в данном случае всё равно придётся прибегнуть к коду, так как при использовании какого-либо отрицающего шаблона движок регулярных выражений просто продолжит поиск совпадений со следующей позиции в строке, в регулярных выражениях .NET нет поддержки `(*SKIP)(*F)` (как в PCRE).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ничего не понял, но согласен :)

Comment: Вкратце: раз уж всё равно без кода не обойтись, лучше уж обойтись без регулярного выражения.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я вообще не любитель регулярок, их сложно понять.

Comment: конечно не регулярка, но всёравно спасибо за старания

Answer (score 2):

Если уж отвечать на поставленный вопрос, то вот:

```
\([^,]*\([^,]*\)[^,]*\)
```

[Проверка](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%5B%5E%2C%5D*%5C%28%5B%5E%2C%5D*%5C%29%5B%5E%2C%5D*%5C%29&i=3.786%20%2B%202x%20*%20%28%281%20%2B%201%20-%20%282%20%2B%204%29%29%20%2B%2012*31%29%20%3D%20pow%283%2C%20-2%285-4%29%29%20%2B%203%2F4)

**Дополнение**

Проблемы предложенного выше варианта очевидны.
Возьмём за основу такой шаблон:

```
(\(([^,()]*\([^,()]+\)[^,()]*)+\))
```

Это РВ ведет себя более предсказуемо в том смысле, что находит скобочные выражения строго одного уровня вложенности.
Т.е. никаких лишних скобок "внутри":
[image: РВ1]

Этот шаблон легко расширить до следующего уровня (и в принципе любого), просто дублируя начальную и конечную конструкцию:

```
(\(([^,()]*\(([^,()]*\([^,()]+\)[^,()]*)+\)[^,()]*)+\))
       <-- ^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

[image: РВ2]

Теперь, объединим эти шаблоны через ИЛИ:

```
(\(([^,()]*\(([^,()]*\([^,()]+\)[^,()]*)+\)[^,()]*)+\))|(\(([^,()]*\([^,()]+\)[^,()]*)+\))
```

[image: РВ3]

[Проверка](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%28%28%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D*%5C%28%28%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D*%5C%28%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D%2B%5C%29%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D*%29%2B%5C%29%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D*%29%2B%5C%29%29%7C%28%5C%28%28%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D*%5C%28%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D%2B%5C%29%5B%5E%2C%28%29%5D*%29%2B%5C%29%29&i=%28%28%281%29%29%20%28%281%2B5%29%29%28%282%2B%282%2B5%295%29%29%28%28%29%29%0D%0A%28%281%29%282%29%29%0D%0A%28%28%281%29%20%2B%20%282%29%29%29%0D%0Ax%20%2B%20%281%20%2B%20%282%20%2B%203%29%20%2B%204%20%2B%20%285%20%2B%206%29%20%2B%207%29%20%2B%20y%20%3D%20pow%283%2C%202%285-4%29%29%0D%0A3.786%20%2B%202x%20*%20%28%281%20%2B%201%20-%20%282%20%2B%204%29%29%20%2B%2012*31%29%20%3D%20pow%283%20%2B%202%285-4%29%29%20%2B%203%2F4)

Это не решает проблему в целом, но для ряда задач с известными ограничениями может подойти.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov почему не правильно, работает же, цитата от автора `пусть хотя бы этот пример и это описание`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov откуда вы знаете, что автору нужно добавлять пару скобок? Он же просил конкретное решение для данного конкретного примера. Автор не раскрывал сути задачи. Поэтому ваше предположение о том, что регулярка не подходит может оказаться неверным. Но ок, каждый думает по-своему, не буду спорить, возможно вы и правы, этого мы тоже не знаем.

Comment: как же вы любите цепляться к словам

Comment: Кстати говоря, если добавить пару скобок, то мы получаем синтаксическую ошибку. Это лишний раз подтверждает выводы коллег, что FSM - наиболее верное направление.